# what is the formula of aspect ratio to set according to screen size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation, aspect-ratio

i want to set gridView in my List. And all gridView's child set according to screen size and aspectRatio.So how can i set aspecRation dynamically according to screen size.

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can access screen sizes and ratio through MediaQuery

ex : `Mediaquery.of(context).size.width`  gives screen width